# Django Haystack + Elasticsearch strange intermittent bug

Tags: django, python-3.x, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm facing a strange issue with [django-haystack](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack) with Elasticsearch.

Everything works great (indexing, querying…), but **sometimes** (and I don't manage to identify the root cause), querying the index crashes with this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
 35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
 128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
 126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
 21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/django/prod/mysite/forum/api.py" in get_topics
 66.     topics_list = SearchQuerySet().filter(**filter).models(Topic)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/haystack/query.py" in __init__
 29.         self._determine_backend()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/haystack/query.py" in _determine_backend
 55.         backend_alias = connection_router.for_read(**hints)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/haystack/utils/loading.py" in for_read
 167.         return self._for_action('for_read', False, **hints)[0]

Exception Type: IndexError at /forum/api/get-topics/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

The issue seems to be with the `_determine_backend` function.

My backend is configured this way in Django settings file:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch2_backend.Elasticsearch2SearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'myindex',
    },
}
```

It's the same on my production server (Python 3.5) and my dev (Python 3.6).

Haystack version is:

```
django-haystack==2.8.1
  - Django [required: >=1.11, installed: 2.0.6]
    - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2018.4]
elasticsearch==2.4.1
  - urllib3 [required: <2.0,>=1.8, installed: 1.23]
```

Have you ever experienced such a thing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share the error you see in the ES server logs ?

Comment: Hum, nothing specific in ES logs. In fact, I think haystack fails before calling ES.

Comment: Have you set a custom `HAYSTACK_ROUTERS` setting?

Comment: No solaissmoke, no custom `HAYSTACK_ROUTERS` :( It should default to `['haystack.routers.DefaultRouter']`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using threaded workers in your app server and django-haystack is not thread-safe by default. See the warning [here](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/blob/master/docs/views_and_forms.rst):

> Warning
>
> The standard SearchView is not thread-safe. Use the
> search_view_factory function, which returns thread-safe instances of
> SearchView.

One solution is to not use threaded workers in the app server, e.g. in Gunicorn, start the app server with `--workers X` instead of `--workers X --threads Y`. But that may impact your app performance.

An alternative solution is to coerce `SearchQuerySet` to use the `default` connection, as suggested [here](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1620#issuecomment-1416193582), but simplified as follows in your code:

```
topics_list = SearchQuerySet(using='default').filter(**filter).models(Topic)
```